# Sunspot search ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm using Sunspot (https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) with Rails.

Here's my model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    boolean :red
    boolean :blue
    boolean :green
    ...
  end
end
```

Consider the following search:

```
Item.search
  any_of do
    with :red, true
    with :blue, true
    with :green, true
  end
end
```

How can I order the results like this: items containing all of the colors followed by items containing 2 of the colors followed by items containing 1 of the colors?

**Note**: This is just one example search. The answer should consider all possible search combinations for the colors.

**Update 1**

Ordering by number of colors won't work. For example, say you have the items:

1. green/blue
2. green/red/black

If you search for green and blue, item 2 will come before item 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but would probably do the trick:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    boolean :red
    boolean :blue
    boolean :green
    integer :number_of_colors, :stored => true
  end

  def number_of_colors
    # implementation may vary
    count=0
    self.attributes.each do |k,v|
      if %w(red blue green).include?(k.to_s) && v?
        count += 1
      end
    end
    count
  end
end
```

Then, after re-indexing:

```
Item.search
  any_of do
    with :red, true
    with :blue, true
    with :green, true
    order_by :number_of_colors, :desc
  end
end
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think it'll work. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I didn't think that there where other colors at play... Thanks for the update. In this case, another option would be to collapse all of the object's color codes (names) in one `text` field in the searchable block, and then run a full-text search on on that field, using all of the needed colors as keyword. Object that would get more matches would get highest relevancy score, and would be returned first. Something like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :color_codes, :stored => true
  end

  # will return "green blue " for item1 above
  # will return "green red black " for item2 above
  def color_codes
    # implementation may vary
    colors=""
    self.attributes.each do |k,v|
      if %w(red blue green black ...).include?(k.to_s) && v?
        colors += "#{k} "
      end
    end
    colors
  end
end
```

Then, your search routine would look like:

```
q = "green blue"
Item.search do
  keywords q do
    fields :color_codes
  end
end
```

item1 above would get exact match when searched on "green blue", and will come up first.